# Does an equivalent of 'chrome.storage' exist in safari?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, safari, progressive-web-apps, google-chrome-storage

I was looking for a way to share the `localstorage` accross multiple devices (same account), without needing a backend service. For chrome, I found their [storage api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage), so you can sync data between different devices on your google account.

This is a very convenient feature, but does something like this also exist for safari?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this, @codepleb?

Comment: @Seth Sadly no. :/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do this via creating an extension. Porting it to safari (I think this is supported). Then using the chrome storage using that extension. Depending on what you want to do with chrome storage, is what you want to make the chrome extension. So say you just want to store data, you could just create an extension that has an input. That saves that to a Local or Sync chrome storage. (Most likely local)